# Number of tasks not equal to number of partitions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark application that does the following

1. Read files from S3
2. Group above data by a 'key' and generate counts per-key
3. Persist key-value pairs to DB

I have modeled the problem as follows

1. Obtain list of files in the driver program and use `sc.parallelize` to generate a RDD of filenames. I am trying to control the `numberOfPartitions` here by using `sc.parallelize(filenameArray, sizeOfFilenameArray)` - let's call this the `filenamesRDD`
2. Download contents for each file from S3 in parallel and map to user defined objects - let's call this RDD the `objectsRDD`
3. Generate a `pairRDD` from the `objectsRDD`
4. Use `reduceByKey` to obtain counts per key - let's call this RDD the `countsRDD`. **Currently due to a bug, I have `numberOfPartitions` for the `countsRDD` set to 1**
5. Use `foreachPartition` to persist `countsRDD` to a DB

I have two environments where I am running the application

- *Test* - 1 Machine with 2 CPUs. Value for `spark.default.parallelism` = 4
- *Prod* - 2 Machines with 16 CPUs each. Value for `spark.default.parallelism` = 32

As expected, my job executes in two stages

- Stage 1 : `filenamesRDD` -> `objectsRDD` -> `pairRDD`
- Stage 2 : `pairRDD` -> `countsRDD` -> *persistToDB*

I am observing that in my Prod environment, the `numberOfTasks` generated for both Stages 1 and 2 doesn't equal the `numberOfParitions` in the corresponding RDDs. I confirmed the value for `numberOfPartitions` by printing it out. Here is an example

`numberOfFiles` = 100

**Test Environment**

- *Stage1*

  - Expectation : `numberOfTasks` = 100, `numberOfParitions` = 100 for `objectsRDD` and `pairRDD`
  - Observation : *Matches Expectation*
- *Stage2*

  - Expectation : `numberOfTasks` = 1, `numberOfPartitions` = 1 for `countsRDD`
  - Reality : *Matches Expectation*

**Prod Environment**

- *Stage1*

  - Expectation : `numberOfTasks` = 100, `numberOfPartitions` = 100 for `objectsRDD` and `pairRDD`
  - Observation : `numberOfTasks` = 16, `numberOfPartitions` = 100 for `objectsRDD` and `pairRDD`
- *Stage2*

  - Expectation : `numberOfTasks` = 1, `numberOfPartitions` = 1 for `countsRDD`
  - Observation : `numberOfTasks` = 16, `numberOfPartitions` = 1 for `countsRDD`

I have read through a lot of material and nowhere have I seen instances and explanations where the `numberOfPartitions != numberOfTasks`. Could someone help figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the two environments have different configuration values. You can view the configurations in the History page "Environment" tab.
I suggest comparing the Test and Prod environment settings.

Comment: Found the issue. Like you said, some of the environment settings were being overridden at deployment time.